# Quick and dirty way to compare SQL server performance

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, benchmarking

Further to my previous question about the [Optimal RAID setup for SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165383/optimal-raid-setup-for-sql-server), could anyone suggest a quick and dirty way of benchmarking the database performance on the new and old servers to compare them? Obviously, the proper way would be to monitor our actual usage and set up all sorts of performance counters and capture the queries, etc., but we are just not at that level of sophistication yet and this isn't something we'll be able to do in a hurry. So in the meanwhile, I'm after something that would be a bit less accurate, but quick to do and still better than nothing. Just as long as it's not misleading, which would be worse than nothing. It should be SQL Server specific, not just a "synthetic" benchmark. It would be even better if we could use our actual database for this.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the performance of your application itself with the new and old servers. It's not necessarily easy:

- Set up a performance test environment with your application on (depending on your architecture this may consist of several machines, some of which may be able to be VMs, but some of which may not be)
- Create "driver" program(s) which give the application simulated work to do
- Run batches of work under the same conditions - remember to reboot the database server between runs to nullify effects of caching (Otherwise your 2nd and subsequent runs will probably be amazingly fast)

Ensure that the performance test environment has enough hardware machines in to be able to load the database heavily - this may mean swapping out some VMs for real hardware.

Remember to use production-grade hardware in your performance test environment - even if it is expensive.

Our database performance test cluster contains six hardware machines, several of which are production-grade, one of which contains an expensive storage array. We also have about a dozen VMs on a 7th simulating other parts of the service.

Answer (score 0):

you can always insert, read, and delete a couple of million rows - it's not a realistic mix of operations but it should strain the disks nicely...

Answer (score 0):

Find at least a couple of the queries that are taking some time, or at least that you suspect are taking time, insert a lot of data if you don't have it already, and run the queries having set:
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON
Those should give you a rough idea of the resources being consumed.

You can also run SQL Server Profiler to get a general idea of what queries are taking a long time and how long they are taking plus other statistics. It outputs a lot of data so try to filter it down a little bit, possibly by long duration or one of the other performance statistics.